# 10000 rounded to the nearest integer is 22

Tags: mathematics, pattern

10000 rounded to the nearest integer is 22,

20000 rounded to the nearest integer is 2101,

100000 rounded to the nearest integer is 212, and

200000 rounded to the nearest integer is 21010.

What is 1000000 rounded to the nearest integer?

Comment: That looks like rot13(greanel)…

Comment: It's rot13(greanel) but more acronym(greanel).

Comment: 81 => 8
162 => 64
243 => 20
486 => 192
Not seeing a pattern...

Comment: That's because you interpreted my earlier comment incorrectly.

Comment: Also, "rounded to the nearest integer" is a BIG clue.

Comment: It's probably some rot13(qvivfvba) as well, but how is greanel/rot13(greanel) an acronym?

Comment: greanel is an acronym. If you find the acronym, you would be able to interpret my comment correctly.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake earlier. I fixed it now.

Comment: I couldn't find greanel anywhere. Should this be in chat?

Comment: OOps, I meant anagram(greanel).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1000000 rounded to the nearest integer is

> 2102

This is because

> The numbers are written in base 3/2.

As a result,

> 10000 = $(3/2)^4$ = 81/16. This rounds to 5, which in base 3/2 is 22. 
>  20000 = $2(3/2)^4$ = 162/16. This rounds to 10, which in base 3/2 is 2101. 
>  100000 = $(3/2)^5$ = 243/32. This rounds to 8, which in base 3/2 is 212. 
>  200000 = $2(3/2)^5$ = 486/32. This rounds to 15, which in base 3/2 is 21010. 
>  1000000 = $(3/2)^6$ = 729/64. This rounds to 11, which in base 3/2 is 2102.